# data is not save in database

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working in CakePHP. I want to save posted data into my database.So I have created function in controller that looks like below :

```
function add_news()
{
    $this->_checkSession();
    $this->layout = "admin_inner";

    if(!empty($this->params['form'])) 
    {   
        $tit = $this->params['form']['title'];
        $con = $this->params['form']['content'];
        $query = "insert into news(news_title,news_content) values('".$tit."','".$con."')";
        echo $query;
        $this->News->query($query);
    }

    Configure::write('debug', '2');
}
```

I print query and execute in database then it works fine.But here it does not execute.I do not have **News** model.

**Note :** I am working in CakePHP 1.3.13

Comment: Not familiar with cakePHP, but is that really the way to insert data in cakePHP? I can hardly believe that. Doesn't cakePHP have a QueryBuilder or something like that?

Comment: @Daan So how can I insert data into database using **save()**?I have tried using **save()** but its not working.

Comment: Everything you need to know: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#saving-your-data

Comment: what version of cakephp are you using

Comment: @Tonystark I have mention it above.Its 1.3.13

Comment: How your url looks like?What is your controller name?And is your current controller has  a valid model?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to know how to insert data in cakephp ....link for this is :- http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html

then you can try this code to insert data in table

```
if(!empty($this->params['form'])) 
{   
    $tit = $this->params['form']['title'];
    $con = $this->params['form']['content'];

    $data = array(
            "news_title"=>$tit,
            "news_content"=>$con

            );
    $this->News->save($data);       

}
```

Comment: he is using cake 1.3

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_news()
{
    $this->_checkSession();
    $this->layout = "admin_inner";

    if(!empty($this->params['form'])) 
    {   
        $tit = $this->params['form']['title'];
        $con = $this->params['form']['content'];
        $data = array(
            "news_title"=>$tit,
            "news_content"=>$con

           );
     $this->News->save($data); 
   }

   Configure::write('debug', '2');
```

}